# yum install error: protected multilib versions error

Tags: yum, headers, openssl, rhel-6

I am trying to install the development headers for openssl on a RHEL 6.1 system, but get the following error:

```
$sudo yum install  openssl-devel.x86_64


<SNIP>
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Protected multilib versions: openssl-1.0.0-10.el6.i686 != openssl-1.0.0-10.el6_1.4.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I performed a

```
sudo yum downgrade openssl
sudo yum install openssl-devel.
```

and now things seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this means that there is version skew bewteen architectures (thre is a clash between files common to several architectures. This should be reported as a bug.